# Jquery on(click) issue and change the click target

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, onclick

I have basic HTML with basic JQuery code both as the following :

**HTML code:**

```
<section id="footer-extras">
  <div class="footer-extras point1">
    <div id="footer-float" class="point1">
      <span id="f-search" class="f-search">
        <span id="fsearchselector" class="circle">
          <span class="default">ONLY CLICK</span>
          <span id="fsearchcontent" class="content rmclass">
            CONTENT SHOW / HIDE
          </span>
        </span>
      </span>
      <span class="fextras-wrapper">
        <span id="fextraselector" class="circle">
          <span class="default">ONLY CLICK</span>
          <span id="fextrascontent" class="content rmclass">
            CONTENT SHOW / HIDE
          </span>
        </span>
      </span>
      <span class="f-menu-wrapper">
        <span id="fmenuselector" class="circle">
          <span class="default">ONLY CLICK</span>
          <span class="content rmclass">
            CONTENT SHOW / HIDE
          </span>
        </span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**JQuery code :**

```
 $(function(){ //F1
        $("#footer-float > span > span > .default").on("click",function(event){
                $(this).next().toggleClass('rmclass');
                $("#footer-float > span > span > .default").not(event.currentTarget).next().addClass('rmclass');
            });
            $(document).on("mouseup touchstart", function (event){
                var container = $("#footer-float > span > span > .default").next();
                if (!$(event.target).parent().hasClass("circle_opened circle")) {
                        $("span.circle_opened").removeClass("circle_opened");
                        $(container).addClass('rmclass');
                }
            });

}); //Parent function
```

My issue started when I click the target as the following :

1. First click should open the hidden menu  by toggleClass ==> **OK**
2. The second click on the same target ==> **Not OK**, as the click
   transferred to the new span shown. (hidden content container)
3. Click  out the container close all open panels ==> **OK** If I will
   remove the second Function of the code `//F2`: the first function
   will work just fine.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   var event = event;
  $(function(){ //F1
   $("#footer-float > span > span > .default").on("click",function(event){
     $(this).next().toggleClass('rmclass');
     $("#footer-float > span > span > .default").not(event.currentTarget).next().addClass('rmclass');
    });
    $(document).on("mouseup touchstart", function (event){
     var container = $("#footer-float > span > span > .default").next();
     if (!$(event.target).parent().hasClass("circle_opened circle")) {
       $("span.circle_opened").removeClass("circle_opened");
       $(container).addClass('rmclass');
     }
    });

 }); //Parent function
}); //Document Ready function
```

```css
section > div > div > * {
display:block;
width:auto;
margin: 20px 0;
padding:10px;
border:2px solid #333;
text-align:center
}
span {display: block;}

.rmclass {
  display:none;
  border:1px solid blue;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.default {
  font-weight:bolder;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="footer-extras">
  <div class="footer-extras point1">
    <div id="footer-float" class="point1">
      <span id="f-search" class="f-search">
        <span id="fsearchselector" class="circle">
          <span class="default">ONLY CLICK</span>
          <span id="fsearchcontent" class="content rmclass">
            CONTENT SHOW / HIDE
          </span>
        </span>
      </span>
      <span class="fextras-wrapper">
        <span id="fextraselector" class="circle">
          <span class="default">ONLY CLICK</span>
          <span id="fextrascontent" class="content rmclass">
            CONTENT SHOW / HIDE
          </span>
        </span>
      </span>
      <span class="f-menu-wrapper">
        <span id="fmenuselector" class="circle">
          <span class="default">ONLY CLICK</span>
          <span class="content rmclass">
            CONTENT SHOW / HIDE
          </span>
        </span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Where is the issue in my functions please ?

1. What I expect, **ONLY CLICK** it will toggleClass
2. When I click any place in body, it will add/remove class

Can you check the demo below and give advise how to correct this as I spent time to try searching for solution with no luck.

Thank you,
Tariq

Comment: Unable to understand your issue. Please explain

Comment: in the code snippet, ONLY CLICK is marked by red...its toggle Class for the first click, (Remov/Add) class. What I want, to keep the toggle class action stick to it and the second function will also do the click on document body.
If you check the demo, you can not toggle class with ONLY CLICK div

Comment: Yes, the first function will toggle class only for ONLY CLICK span. and the second function will **add** the class again to it , igonre the other class as its for something else

Comment: Or to make it simple, I need both function work together and please forgave my english

Comment: both function you mean event ? click and mouseup touchstart

Comment: I have 2 function one for toggleClass and second function for mouseup touchstart , I need to keep the toggleClass working as it and also to make the second function (mouseup touchstart ) work as it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know if the below is what you're searching for ,
but I've just checked in touch event if the target is the ONLY CLICK span , otherwise trigger event .

```
if(!$(event.target).hasClass("default")) {
   // touch event code 
}
```

```js
$(function() { //F1

  $("#footer-float > span > span > .default").on("click", function(event) {
  console.log("e");
    $(this).next().toggleClass('rmclass');
    $("#footer-float > span > span > .default").not(event.currentTarget).next().addClass('rmclass');
  });

  $(document).on("mouseup touchstart", function(event) {  
    console.log(event.target);
    if(!$(event.target).hasClass("default")) {
      var container = $("#footer-float > span > span > .default").next();
      if (!$(event.target).parent().hasClass("circle_opened circle")) {
         $("span.circle_opened").removeClass("circle_opened");
         $(container).addClass('rmclass');
      }
    }
  });

}); //Parent function
```

```css
section>div>div>* {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  margin: 20px 0;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  text-align: center
}

span {
  display: block;
}

.rmclass {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.default {
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="footer-extras">
  <div class="footer-extras point1">
    <div id="footer-float" class="point1">
      <span id="f-search" class="f-search">
        <span id="fsearchselector" class="circle">
          <span class="default">ONLY CLICK</span>
      <span id="fsearchcontent" class="content rmclass">
            CONTENT SHOW / HIDE
          </span>
      </span>
      </span>
      <span class="fextras-wrapper">
        <span id="fextraselector" class="circle">
          <span class="default">ONLY CLICK</span>
      <span id="fextrascontent" class="content rmclass">
            CONTENT SHOW / HIDE
          </span>
      </span>
      </span>
      <span class="f-menu-wrapper">
        <span id="fmenuselector" class="circle">
          <span class="default">ONLY CLICK</span>
      <span class="content rmclass">
            CONTENT SHOW / HIDE
          </span>
      </span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you this fixed the issue, The general ide is fixed, but I have other issue, I will fix myself :)

Comment: You're welcome :) , just describe here what's the other issue , if it's the same code , otherwise post a new quest :)

Comment: No thank you, its related to other part, which is not included in the HTML file, I will check and If I will face issue, I will be back here :) Thank you again and again